# real time chat pop-up notification using ajax

Tags: ajax

I'm a beginner trying to learn and create a personal project. What I want is to create a simple chat application with pop-up notifications whenever a user sends a message. I'm having a hard time and I've been stuck on this for like 3 days now.

PS: The goal is to use Vanilla ajax or JS. Don't want to use any plugins like pusher or anything.

here's my php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chat System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="centeralised">
        <div class="chathistory"></div>
        <div class="chatbox">
            <form action="" method="POST">          
                <textarea class="txtarea" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        loadChat();
        });
    
        $('#message').keyup(function(e){
            var message = $(this).val();
            // alert (message);
            if( e.which == 13 ){
                $.post('handlers/ajax.php?action=SendMessage&message='+message, function(response){             
                    loadChat();
                    $('#message').val('');
                });
            }
        });   

        var lastResponse = ''
        function loadChat()
        {
            $.post('handlers/ajax.php?action=getChat', function(response){
                $('.chathistory').html(response);

                //sound notification
                    if (response !== lastResponse) {
                        var audio = new Audio('notification.mp3')
                        audio.play()
                
                    }
                    lastResponse = response
            });
        }
        setInterval(function(){
            loadChat();
        }, 1000);
        
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

my ajax file:

```
<?php

include("../config.php");

if( isset($_REQUEST['action']) ){

    switch( $_REQUEST['action'] ){

        case "SendMessage":

            session_start();

            $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO chat SET user=?, message=?");
            $query->execute([$_SESSION['user'], $_REQUEST['message']]);


        break;

        case "getChat":

            $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from chat");
            $query->execute();

            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            
            $chat = '';
            foreach( $rs as $r ){

            $chat .= $r->user.' says:  '.$r->message.'<hr/>';

            }   

            echo $chat;

        break;
    }
}
?>
```

config file:

```
<?php

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "chat_system";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = '';


    try{
        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbhost=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

PPS: idk if this will help but I found this code on google, but I don't know how to edit to work on my code.

```
case "popup":

     $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `user` where seen_status='0' order by userid desc");
                $output = '';
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $output .= '
                    <div class="alert alert_default">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                        <p>Firstname: <strong>'.$row['firstname'].'</strong><br>
                        Lastname: <strong>'.$row['lastname'].'</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    ';
                }
                 
                mysqli_query($conn,"update `user` set seen_status='1' where seen_status='0'");
                echo $output;
    
            break;
```

Comment: HI, what doesn't work ?

Comment: there's no pop-up notification. I wanted to add it whenever a user receives a message from another user.

Comment: what does response has here `$('.chathistory').html(response)` ?

Comment: yeah it gets the chat history from the database.